# Steward still offers Furnishing even after all upgrades completed

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

In my homestead, I've built every single upgrade in the house except a few in the cellar. My house is thus fully furnished. I even removed the workbenches.

However, when I talk to my steward, he still offers to furnish the 5 sections of the house for the full cost. I'm assuming that doing so would do nothing.

Do those options ever disappear if you don't buy the furnishings from him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the options do not disappear.  It is an alternate way to furnish your house, but it never checks whether you need to or not.